# Concurrency issues when querying the Google App Engine datastore

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, concurrency

My application is currently facing a problem where a race condition sometimes lead multiple threads to write the same value to the datastore.

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
public void writeToDatastore(ValueObject obj){
   boolean objectExists = checkDatastoreForObject(obj);

   if(!objectExists){
      doSomeStuff();
      writeObjectToDatastore(obj);
   }
}
```

Sometimes, two or more threads read from the datastore before anything has been written, which leads to more than one instance of the object being persisted.

Adding the `synchronized` keyword (or other concurrency constructs) fixes the problem - provided that there is only one instance of the application running.

How can these types of concurrency issues be resolved in a distributed environment?

Comment: You could assign the key id manually, if you have a unique property for each value.  Then, a write writes over the top of the existing value.

Answer (score 1):

When calling Datastore from App Engine, use a transaction. First try to get() the entity to see if it's there. If not, put() the entity.

Here's some sample code that demonstrates transactions using the App Engine API: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/datastore/src/test/java/com/example/appengine/TransactionsTest.java

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention

> Avoiding datastore contention - Datastore contention occurs when a
>   single entity or entity group is updated too rapidly. The datastore
>   will queue concurrent requests to wait their turn. Requests waiting in
>   the queue past the timeout period will throw a concurrency exception.
>   If you're expecting to update a single entity or write to an entity
>   group more than several times per second, it's best to re-work your
>   design early-on to avoid possible contention once your application is
>   deployed.